# ORACLE:SQL REGEXP_SUBSTR that returns the column value after last backslash(/)

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-substr

ORACLE:SQL REGEXP_SUBSTR that returns the column value after last backslash(/)

example: 
https://test/test/test/test/getTest/1234
expected value: 1234

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regular expressions for this. You can simply using `substr` and `instr` which are likely to perform faster:

```
select
  substr(col, instr(col, '/', -1) + 1)
from t;
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/EFBD43479)

If you must use `regexp_substr` (for some reason) then use:

```
select regexp_substr(col, '[^/]+$') from t;
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/JJG40047)

Answer (score 0):

If you need with REGEXP_SUBSTR also, then:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('https://test/test/test/test/getTest/1234' , '[^/]+$' )  from dual
```